# Private External Git on Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Is there any way to configure the deployment center of a function, as below, using the az cli?

[image]

I tried to use `az functionapp deployment source config`, but I didn't find any parameter to put the password and user.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you have parameters available to provide the authentication information:

https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/cli/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-source-config

```py
[--private-repo-password]
[--private-repo-username]
```

However I don't get these as options when using the Azure CLI `-h` (not even in the latest version in cloud shell). Not sure if the auto-complete is just failing to parse them or they're not available at all.